# Zend Framework 1.9.x and Firebug

Tags: php, zend-framework, firebug, firephp

Anybody here can point me on the right direction on using firebug for logging on Zend 1.9.x ?

I am using this : (from Zend Framework Manual page)

```
// Place this in your bootstrap file before dispatching your front controller
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

// Use this in your model, view and controller files
$logger->log('This is a log message!', Zend_Log::INFO);
```

but its not working at all.

Comment: Hi, what exactly does "not working at all" mean ? Do you get an error ? If you check the HTTP-headers received by your browser with something like "LiveHTTHeaders" extention for firefox, do you see the header that should be sent containing your log message ? As a precaution : did you install the FirePHP extension ?

Comment: By not working means I didnt get anything on the firebug console, and yes I have installed firePHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after making sure that you had a firephp installed you can check out these vedio for more informations about ZF and Firebug || how to work Firephp and how to debug a sample ajax request STEP BY STEP and even how to create a firebug action helper

part 1 : http://www.zendcasts.com/debugging-zend-projects-with-firebug/2009/08/

part 2 : http://www.zendcasts.com/custom-action-helpers-for-firebug/2009/08/

hopefully this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Simple question: Have you Installed FirePHP for Firebug? :)

Comment: yes I have installed firePHP, it worked when I was using 1.6.x